# Depolarisation of Light in Optical Fibre

Tags: optics, visible-light, polarization, optical-materials

I have a question for which I can't seem to find a solid answer in literature and wondered if anyone could offer advice or reliable references please:

How does light depolarise in non-polarisation-maintaining (i.e. low birefringence) single mode optical fibres?

I believe that if you inject linearly polarised light into a low birefringence fibre (e.g. standard telecomms fibre) it will depolarise as it propagates due to random fluctuations in fibre birefringence. I wonder, over what distance this must typically occur for the light to fully depolarise?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have an ideally straight fiber, that does not move or vibrate, constant and uniform temperature, no strain and so on, the light at the output will be linearly polarized as on the input for a standard telecom fiber. From the low birefringence the polarization will be rotated though. But the output is polarized.

This polarization angle is strongly depending on fiber parameters and is hence not stable, when there is vibration, temperature change, etc...

So light wont be depolarized, it is just undefined polarization angle.

A polarization maintaining fiber is artificially highly birefringent so that the mentioned "random contribution" to birefringence is negligible and the fiber output has stable polarization rotation angle.

Comment: Even if the conditions in the first sentence are satisfied, I would think you could lose polarization due to the fact that different parts of the wave are being reflected from portions of the surface that have different orientations.

Comment: How should it be possible to achieve depolarization from a single mode fiber (under these ideal conditions)?

In a "single" mode fiber you only have two modes. Even if there are distortions/imperfections that cause birefringence there are only two. In any case the superposition of the two modes is always polarized. The output polarization is just very sensitive to tiny differences in these propagation constants.